# Git - Give merged branch a tag

Tags: git, gitlab

can I give a merged branch a tag? The idea behind is I forgot to tag some branches with the latest release tag and I won't revert the branches to tag and remerge them.

Comment: You can tag _any_ commit. You cannot tag a branch, as branches move as you commit on them, while tags stay stationary (i.e. you can tag a commit that a branch is currently on, but the branch itself can move on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create tags pointing to whatever commit you need. Like branches, it doesn't modify its target commit in any way, it's only a new label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I try to find the command to add the tag to a commit but all commands seems to create a tag.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

My basic idea was something like `git tag tagName commitSHA`

Comment: @phng Tags are unmovable by design. Recreate a tag pointing to the commit you want, but you won't really move an existing tag without deleting and recreating it. What's the fonctional problem you're trying to solve by moving this tag?

Comment: Moving the tag? Ahm, the initial situation is I created a tag, lets call it `2.2`, and wanted to start using it for the upcoming merges. But I forgot to use the tag and now I want to tag my merged commits with `2.2`.

Comment: Are you somehow considering tagging multiple commits with the same tag? Or did I just overinterpret your point? A tag points to *one* object.

Comment: oh, then I probably reconsider my release workflow. Do you have any good tips or articles about release workflows? My current idea was:

1. Create issue
2. link branch and MR with issue
3. create milestone with release tag connection
4. link issue with milestone
5. link commits with release tag to have a better overview and access to changes that happend in specific release versions

Comment: @phng This is not only *another* question, it's a quite large one. Could you try to formulate it separately? It'll be more visible for everyone to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248030/git-how-to-bind-changes-of-multiple-mrs-under-a-new-release-tag-version

Answer (score 2):

You can give any commit a tag.

Tags do not mark *branches;* tag mark *commits*.<sup>1</sup>  A tag marks one specific commit, either directly—a lightweight tag—or with some additional information, such as a PGP signature, or release information, or whatever you'd like to include via what Git calls an *annotated tag*.

Note that a *branch name* also just marks one specific commit.  The key difference between a branch name like `feature/tall` and a tag like `v1.2.3` is that the branch name is *supposed* to move, and will move automatically as you add new commits, while the tag name is *not* supposed to move: it is supposed to provide a human-readable, and perhaps semantically meaningful, name that names that one particular commit forever.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unlike branch names, tag names and annotated tag objects are not restricted to tagging only commits.  You can create a tag name that points to a tree object or blob object, or to another annotated tag object.  There is never<sup>2</sup> any reason to do this though.

<sup>2</sup>What, never?  Well, hardly ever!  (You are allowed to invent your own.  Git provides a set of tools, not a particular solution.)