# Git - How to bind changes of multiple MRs under a new release tag / version?

Tags: git, gitlab

my current workflow to handle and resolve issues in GitLab is the following (I will define the problem after it):

1. create a milestone with connected release tag via Release API
2. connect issues to the milestone
3. automatically create MRs and branches connected to the issue via GitLab UI (for consistent naming)
4. Make MR changes
5. Merge MR and close the issue automatically

The problem here is how I handle the tag. Its absolutely not a part of the updates workflow because when I create it, it gets the latest master before I make the changes.

#### But how do I bind all my changes under a release version?

One idea was to merge all changes into a *release branch* and to connect this branch to the tag but the problem is GitLab doesn't close the issues either their MRs are merged with the release branch or when the release branch is merged. And this is a problem because the milestone overview would become redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags aren't really meant to work that way. Generally they are used to mark a point in the repo's history that has certain functionality. Frequently this is a release name/number or version number.

It looks like your same workflow will work if you just move the tag to the end, *after* you've merged the MR into master.

You can read up on tags in the git documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: Ok, this makes it clearer now what the point of tags are, thanks.
Its the first time I created a workflow with GitLab. What are your thoughts about my previously written idea?
And tagging the last commit of my milestone's updates means I already merged all the new changes into the master. I guess there are some workflows out there where the master becomes builded after a merge and the production release gets an update. Creating a tag all after this sounds not really fluent. Or is it a common method?

Comment: Yep, this is pretty close to what I do on my team. Our work is done in feature branches, then when we decide which branches/user stories will be part of the next release, we merge the feature branches into a "release" branch that our QA works on to approve/reject. If approved, we merge the release branch into master, then tag it. Works pretty well for us.

Comment: This way the issues that are connected to MRs with `closes #1` in the description will not be automatically closed, or not? I guess you manually close them to have a correct milestone overview?

Comment: That functionality shouldn't change. You can close issues that way in Merge Requests no matter the workflow you use, or if you use tags and milestones at all.